# How to add a CSS wrapper class to the MUI generated styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to add the parent CSS class name to the generated styles. This is needed to increase the priority of styles, because my React app is mounted to an existing site with its own styles.

For example, I have the following generated class name (styles) for the `Typography` component:

```
.css-xg4ew6-MuiTypography-root {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 1.167;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
```

How to make it like this:

```
.MY-CUSTOM-CSS-WRAPPER-CLASS .css-xg4ew6-MuiTypography-root {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 1.167;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
```

It should be for every CSS class.